# Sum of unique entries per day

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table structure like this :

```
ID    commission     transdate           token 

1      10         2013-11-22 08:24:00    token1
2      10         2013-11-22 08:24:00    token1
3      10         2013-11-22 08:24:00    token1
4      10         2013-11-22 08:24:00    token1
5      10         2013-11-22 08:24:00    token1
6      29         2013-11-22 06:24:00    token2
7      29         2013-11-22 06:24:00    token2
```

The thing is that I have duplicate entries in my table for some data and I need to filter it out while taking the SUM. If the transdate is same and the token is same, I only need to consider one entry for the sum. The sum I need is sum of all the commission for all token grouped by date.

How can I do this through query  ?

Comment: use `group by` on `date` and `token`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) with [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(comission), 
  token, 
  DATE(transdate) 
FROM
  t 
GROUP BY 
  token, 
  DATE(transdate)
```

Answer (score 2):

try below query,

To consider only one entry for date for a particular token:

```
SELECT commission,
       date(transdate),
       token 
FROM tokens 
GROUP BY date(transdate),
         token;
```

To get a sum of commission for date

```
SELECT SUM(commission),
       DATE(transdate),
       token 
FROM tokens 
GROUP BY DATE(transdate),
         token;
```

[Sql Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/614c3/8)

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
SELECT SUM(commission), token, transdate FROM tableName GROUP BY token, transdate
```